# Converting complex RDD to a flatten RDD with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following CSV (sample)

```
 id     timestamp         routeid   creationdate        parameters
 1000  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    RSRP=-102,
 1002  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    RA Req. SN=-146,TPC=4,RX Antennas=-8,   
 1003  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    RA Req. SN=134,RX Antennas=-91,MCS=-83,TPC=-191,
```

Basically I want to separate parameters from one column into multiple columns as followed :

```
id , timestamp, routeid, creationdate, RSRP ,RA REQ. SN, TPC,RX Antennas,MCS
```

So if there is no value of any parameter for that, I would put the value as NULL like instead :

```
 1000  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55 -102 NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

And if the value exists fill out the rows,

This is what I have tried :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import os
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import itertools
import re

sc = SparkContext("local","Work")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('file:///sample.csv')

def aaa(a):
    aa = a.split(',', 15000)
    filtered = filter(lambda p: not re.match(r'^\s*$', p), aa)           
    listWithNoEmptyLines = [z for z in filtered if z != []]

    for x in listWithNoEmptyLines:
       ab = x.split("=")
        AllList = []
        rsrp = "" 
        ra_req_sn = ""
        tpc = ""
        rx_antenas = ""
        mcs = ""
         if 'RSRP' in ab:
            rsrp = ab[1]
         else:
            rsrp = "NULL"
         if 'RA Req. SN' in ab:
            ra_req_sn = ab[1]
         else:
            ra_req_sn = "NULL"
         if 'TPC' in ab:
            tpc = ab[1]
         else:
            tpc = "NULL"
         if 'RX Antennas' in ab:
             rx_antenas = ab[1]
         else:
             rx_antenas = "NULL"
         if 'MCS' in ab:
             mcs = ab[1]
         else:
            mcs = "NULL"
    return rsrp,ra_req_sn,tpc,rx_antenas
DFtoRDD  = df1.rdd.map(list).map(lambda x: [str(x[1]), str(x[2]), str(x[3]), aaa(str(x[4]))])
print DFtoRDD.collect()
```

Giving me following result,

```
[['1000','21-11-2016 22:55', '14', '21-11-2016 22:55', ('-102', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL')], ['1002',21-11-2016 22:55', '14', '21-11-2016 22:55', ('NULL', '-146', 'NULL', 'NULL')], ['1003','21-11-2016 22:55', '14', '21-11-2016 22:55', ('NULL', '134', 'NULL', 'NULL')]]
```

Expected results :

```
   id     timestamp         routeid   creationdate        RSRP    RA Req. SN   TPC   RX Antennas MCS
  1000  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    -102      NULL        NULL    NULL       NULL
  1002  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    NULL    -146         4        -8        NULL   
  1003  21-11-2016 22:55     14      21-11-2016 22:55    NULL    134       -191       -91       -83
```

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: This is more like a regex problem than spark.

Comment: yes so in function aaa how can we apply the regex?? or can we create dataframe and transform it? @elisash i want to separate the parameters column by checking the attributes in it and create columns for each attributes and its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define an udf as followed and then select each field. I have used the same data you did with a tab separator.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df1 = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true',delimiter='\t').load('./sample.txt')
df1.show()
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
# |  id|       timestamp|routeid|    creationdate|          parameters|
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
# |1000|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|          RSRP=-102,|
# |1002|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|RA Req. SN=-146,T...|
# |1003|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|RA Req. SN=134,RX...|
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Now let's define our UDF as mentioned above :

```
import re
def f_(s):
    pattern = re.compile("([^,=]+)=([0-9\-]+)")
    return dict(pattern.findall(s or ""))
```

We can test the function directly on a "simple" sample :

```
f_("RA Req. SN=134,RX Antennas=-91,MCS=-83,TPC=-191,")
# {'RA Req. SN': '134', 'RX Antennas': '-91', 'TPC': '-191', 'MCS': '-83'}
```

Ok it's working. We can now register to use in SQL :

```
spark.udf.register("f", f_, MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

spark.sql("SELECT f('RA Req. SN=134,RX Antennas=-91,MCS=-83,TPC=-191,')").show()
# +---------------------------------------------------+
# |f(RA Req. SN=134,RX Antennas=-91,MCS=-83,TPC=-191,)|
# +---------------------------------------------------+
# |                               Map(RA Req. SN ->...|
# +---------------------------------------------------+
```

But in your case, I think that you'll be interested in an actually udf for each field :

```
extract = udf(f_,  MapType(StringType(), StringType()))

df1.select(df1['*'], extract(df1['parameters']).getItem('RSRP').alias('RSRP')).show()
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+----+
# |  id|       timestamp|routeid|    creationdate|          parameters|RSRP|
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+----+
# |1000|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|          RSRP=-102,|-102|
# |1002|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|RA Req. SN=-146,T...|null|
# |1003|21-11-2016 22:55|     14|21-11-2016 22:55|RA Req. SN=134,RX...|null|
# +----+----------------+-------+----------------+--------------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks eliasah, How can i add your solution in my code, i am not getting. can u help

Comment: Thanks a lot eliasah, You really saved me

Comment: Sure sir. can i apply multiple getItem() in single statement??