# How to convert dict to spark map output

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with spark and python. I would like to transform my input dataset.

My input dataset (RDD)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id |                  var                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |"[{index: 1, value: 200}, {index: 2, value: A}, ...]" |
| 2  |"[{index: 1, value: 140}, {index: 2, value: C}, ...]" |
| .. |                      ...                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to have this DataFrame (output dataset)

```
----------------------
| id | index | value |
----------------------
| 1  |  1    | 200   |
| 1  |  2    | A     |
| 1  |  ...  | ...   |
| 2  |  1    | 140   |
| 2  |  2    | C     |
| ...|  ...  | ...   |
----------------------
```

I create a map function

```
def process(row):
    my_dict = {}
    for item in row['value']:
        my_dict['id'] = row['id']
        my_dict['index'] = item['index']
        my_dict['value'] = item['value']

    return my_dict
```

I would like to map my process function like this:

```
output_rdd = input_rdd.map(process)
```

Is it possible to do this on this way (or a simpler way)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting complex RDD to a flatten RDD with PySpark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632030/converting-complex-rdd-to-a-flatten-rdd-with-pyspark)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. My problem is slightly different. I have nested fields and the selection of the columns is done under certain conditions. But this post gives me a starting place to answer response.

Comment: That's why I have shared it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
output_rdd = input_rdd.map(lambda row:process(row)).flatMap(lambda x: x)
```